# Magento 2 - Get product final price in a block

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-attribute

How can I get product `final_price` attribute (affected by a catalog price rule) in a block?
I've tried in this way without success: `$this->_productFactory->create()->load($idProd);`

I've found `price` attribute only.

How can I do?

Comment: I guess it depends what Block you're in. You could also override the current Block to add logic to get the product's price.

Comment: I'm in my custom block (`class Discount extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`) and it is called in `product/list.phtml` template.
I would like to calculate the product discount so I need `price` and `final_price` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging (by Xdebug) I noted that `$this->_productFactory->create()->load($idProd)` object contains `price` property but not `final_price` one, so trying to print `$this->_productFactory->create()->load($idProd)->getData('final_price');` it doesn't return a value; it works if you try with `$this->_productFactory->create()->load($idProd)->getFinalPrice();`

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to get the `final_price` for the product in `/product/view/hero.phtml`. 
So that I could display the stickers based on the discount. Below is what worked for me after spending some time in Magento core:

```
$finalPriceModel = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
```

It will return the instance of `Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice`. Which has a method `getValue()` method defined to return the amount in float. So to just get the amount:

```
$finalPriceAmt = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();
```

I haven't tried this code snippet on `list.phtml`. But it should work as long as $_product is an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

getProduct()->getSpecialPrice() != null): ?>
                Old Price :
        formatPrice($item->getProduct()->getPrice());?>
                
            formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()) ?>