# How to pass price into my own div block

Tags: magento-2.1, price, product-view, render

In magento 2, I've created a recently viewed items using Magento Reports block. Now I need to show prices for only registered users.

I have 2 problems,

1. price is rendered by following php code,

   ```
   echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
       $_item,
       \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
       \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
       [
           'price_id_suffix' => '-' . $type
       ]
   );
   ```

When it renders, chrome inspector shows multiple div classes and spans, which makes my css obsolete. I need to just get the price value given from above block and put inside my own div block. How can I do that? From where this price comes from?

please help me

Answer (score 1):

If your block extend "**AbstractProduct**"

```
(namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product)
```

Then you can use different Price Render or create your own, example found in the core code :

```
echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
    $_product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_VIEW,
    [
        'price_id_suffix' => '_clone'
    ]
)


echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_product,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                            [
                                'price_id_suffix' => '-widget-viewed-' . $suffix
                            ]
```

Comment: Hi, I dont know much about magento. I just need to get price and put inside my div tag. can you help me? Im a beginner. How should I put this into my code?

Comment: If you simply want the price, I recommand this post that will helps you getting it from the $product Model : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149076/magento-2-get-product-final-price-in-a-block

Comment: in that question, they are talking about $this->_productFactory->create()->load($idProd); . I don't have it. Im using Magento Reports module from vendor and I just need the price

Comment: You already have your product in $item variable I assume.
You don't need the factory. Call this : $item->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();

Comment: yes. I get what I want from that code, but the thing is I need to apply some styes to it. from this php line, it renders with few divs and spans which I cant edit. so I need to just get the price to put inside my own div tag. for now I wrote some css targeting that auto generated div tags. but thats not what I need to do here

Comment: also if you can, could you explain me how this code provides the output? to where it connected?